# Converting object to timestap - Python

Tags: python, pandas

Intent: I want to minus two dates to get the number of years in two arrays.

I am quite new to Python and require some help in trying to understand how I convert a `dtype` from object to `datetime` in two different formats:

````
count         20000
unique        13674
top       22/7/1998
freq              7
Name: birth_date, dtype: object
  
```timestamp_df.describe
count                      20000
unique                     19944
top       2017-09-27t13:47+00:00
freq                           2
Name: consultation_timestamp, dtype: object

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried to use `pd.datetime` but unsure on the syntax.
TIA
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `strptime` to convert a string into a datetime object and you can use `datetime.timestamp` to convert datetime objects to timestamps

```py
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime('22/7/1998', '%d/%m/%Y')
print(datetime.timestamp(date))
# gives 901058400.0
```

You might also want to try `parse` method from `dateutil`
Note: datetime objects do carry the year information separately, so you could simply use that:

```
from dateutil import parser

d1 = parser.parse('22/7/1998')
d2 = parser.parse('22/7/1918')

print(d1.year - d2.year)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `pd.to_datetime`:

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime("2017-09-27t13:47+00:00")
```

Output:

`Timestamp('2017-09-27 13:47:00+0000', tz='UTC')`

or

```py
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime("22/7/1998")
```

Output:

`Timestamp('1998-07-22 00:00:00')`

Comment: I used this function and it worked. Thanks.